# what error it is? python script linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

the program get the ls directory list print the index of the items, then ask select one item, and print the item but i get this error:

```
./directory.py
from: can't read /var/mail/subprocess
./directory.py: línea 3: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
./directory.py: línea 3: `def listdir (path):'
```

this is my code

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def listdir (path):
    p = Popen(['ls', path,'-t'] , shell=False, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)
    return [path.rstrip('\n') for path in p.stdout.readlines()]

def find(f, seq):

  for item in seq:
    if f == item:
     return item

def listshow(l,i):

    for item in l:

     print i, item
     i = i + 1

dirlist = listdir("/home/juan/")
val = 0
listshow(dirlist, val)

while True:
    try:
     line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
     if not line: break

print dirlist[line]
```

Comment: Your code is not indented properly. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html

Comment: What error did you get?  Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Just run the code yourself, sr2222

Comment: @hd1 He's new to SO, trying to help him learn how to post good questions.  Also, not going to work anyway since I'm not on *nix and I have no `home/juan` directory.

Comment: Once I fixed the indentation problems, the code runs and gives me output. What do you expect it to give you, @user2410421?

Comment: i expect; first the list of the flies with index
like;
0 Documents
1 Images
then ask for the number of index 
get that number an print it
like: chose number 0
Documents

Comment: By the way -- if you want to generate English-language messages to go with your English-language question, you can `export LC_ALL=C` before running your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using strings as list indexes, so it will not work. Change this portion of code

```
while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        if not line: break
```

with this

```
value = None
while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
        if not line: break
        else:
            value = int(line)
            break
    except ValueError:
        print "You have not provided a valid integer"
```

Also note that you are using the index that user gave you without checking it really exists on the array. So you may also do something like this:

```
try:
    print dirlist[line]
except IndexError:
    print "Nope, that element does not exists..."
```

or check this while after you get the number (check if the number given is between 0 and len(dirlist)-1).